# Getting original scope from multiple selected rows in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have *ng-repeat* with items from my scope. Each row has a checkbox. When I click on the button which is outside ng-repeat it should call function from controller and from there I need to know know which checkboxes were selected and get their original scope values. I'm able to get selected checkboxes within controller with

```
$("input:checkbox:checked")
```

but how can I access it's original scope values (for rows which were selected)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never** do DOM manipulation in your controller.

The better ways would be

1. to add items in an array within your controller on selecting, and then on button-click, process the items in the array via a controller method, or
2. Set a boolean property on each item to true on selection, and then on button-click, process items with that boolean property set to true.

If you give us a jsFiddle for your situation, I or somebody else can give you more details.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. My approach to this issue wasn't right and your second point gave me and idea how to do it. I have modified example code from @TestersGonnaTest and here it is http://jsfiddle.net/e6NPw/2/

Comment: I would suggest for a better readability to do 

     selectedItems = $scope.results.filter(function(result){
              return result.selected; 
        });

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6NPw/1/

I have a `$scope.selected` object on the scope and I keep the ids as keys. After that in your function outside your ng-repeat you can pretty much do anything you want, I just make an array of objects like the $scope.results but only with the selected ones.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. It is working, however I have so many columns and it is not very clean when I have to specify every column when creating a new object. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the code on this fiddle in case you don't want to alter $scope.results and have a selected property for each item.

http://jsfiddle.net/e6NPw/4/